# How do I Count the number of parent groups using LINQ and child repo

Tags: linq

I have a List of "Server Group" objects, which contain, "Monitored Servers" which in turn contain "Server Script Statuses".  I have a repo of these script statuses.  Currently I am trying to find the count for the number of Monitored servers.  I have been messing with this for hours now and can't seem to get it.  I keep getting back the count for the number of scripts within each Monitored Server, but I can't get the number of Monitored Servers under a Server Group. I'm new to LINQ, so sorry if this is something stupid.  Thanks all!

```
//This is List of ScriptStatuses

var scriptsInCategory = scriptRepository.ScriptStatuses
        .Where(p => p.MonitoredServer.ServerGroup.ServerCategory.Name == category);

var groupsList = new List<NodeSummaryListViewModel>();

foreach (var s in scriptsInCategory.GroupBy(p=>p.MonitoredServer.ServerGroup.Name))
{
    NodeSummaryListViewModel viewModel = new NodeSummaryListViewModel
    {
        Name = s.First().MonitoredServer.ServerGroup.Name,
        Description = s.First().MonitoredServer.ServerGroup.Description,

        //I want NumServers to be the count of Monitored Servers under the server group
        NumServers = (from z in scriptsInCategory
                        group z by z.MonitoredServer.ServerGroup into g
                        select new { ServerGroup = g.Key, MonSvrCount = g.Count() }).Count(),

        NumOk = PopulateGroupCellData(CellState.Ok, s),
        NumAttention = PopulateGroupCellData(CellState.Attention,s),
        NumCritical = PopulateGroupCellData(CellState.Critical, s),
        NumUnavailable = PopulateGroupCellData(CellState.Unavailable, s),
        NumOffline = PopulateGroupCellData(CellState.Offline, s)

    };
    groupsList.Add(viewModel);

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understand the question properly but does this make sense to you?

```
from g in groups select new{ g, monitoredServers = g.Servers.Count(s=>s.Scripts > 0)}
```

So you get a list of groups with the number of servers which are being monitored within that group.

Answer (score 1):

I think just

```
NumServers = s.Count(),
```

should work.

Comment: Thx for the reply svick, but that actually returns the total number of scripts under the specific server group which is 8. So my hierarchy for my seeded data is: My parent server category has 2 Server groups. My first server group has 2 monitored servers with which each of them contain 4 script statuses.  So the "s.Count()" returns 8 because of the 8 scripts statuses that are under the Database Server group, but I just want it to return 2 for the number of servers under the ServerGroup, not the number of statuses.  Sorry for the confusion...I'll post if I find out the solution. Thx again!